# Integrate non-standard database into application server

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jdbc, wildfly, orientdb

I have to access an OrientDB database (2.0.x), and there is only a JDBC implementation available. Is there a way to configure JPA (Wildfly 8.2) in a way that I can use Orient? How about JPA-dialects?

I tried using a JCA resource adapter wrapped arount the Orient client, but I keep getting exceptions (sometimes), so I wondered about using JPA + JDBC.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: OrientDB (graph DB) has a reduced form of JPA API available from what I remember, so perhaps just use that. http://orientdb.com/docs/last/JPA-Configuration.html